# Project name does not act as prefix while running docker compose up on multiple services

Tags: bash, docker-compose, environment-variables

I have set COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=xxx in .env file in order to customise project name. But when I use the following:

```
docker-compose up --abort-on-container-exit --scale influx=0 kafka=0
```

It throws an error saying -

```
ERROR: No such service: kafka=0
```

If I provide only one service then it scales up/down without any error but breaks down when I provide multiple services. Is there a way to fix this?

Here's the structure of docker-compose.yml file -

```
version: '3'
services:
   influx:
      image: xxx
      volumes:
         - xxx
      ports:
         - xxx
   kafka:
      image: xxx
      volumes:
         - xxx
      ports:
         - xxx
```

Comment: can you share the compose file (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) also?

Comment: I've provided the structure of the docker-compose file above.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is `docker-compose up [options] continers...` and one of the option is `--scale` and it takes one argument. You can, for exmaple:

```
docker-compose up --scale influx=1 --scale kafka=2 kafka influx
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^ - containers, just omit if all
                          ^^^^^^^^ - argument to --scale option
                  ^^^^^^^ - option
```

Comment: This did not work for me. It throws an error saying -

Comment: + docker-compose up --abort-on-container-exit --scale influx=1 --scale kafka=

Comment: ERROR: Number of containers for service "kafka" is not a number

Comment: `--scale kafka=` sooo why is there no number after `=`?

Comment: I don't know why, that's the issue that I'm struggling with for a very long time. It's failing to fetch the user input.